# AJAX GET request recursivly loading files

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation. I would like to load file A from a server which in turn (depending on A's contents) will try to load files A1, A2, A3, ... An and each file `A[1-n]` will in turn load other files and this can keep going. Yes there is an end to it.

Unfortunately I have come to realize that I need to use synchronized `$.ajax requests`, otherwise that first $.ajax call (when finishes loading file A) just returns without going through the rest of the files. My function looks like:

```
loadFile = function (path, file, scope)
{
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (responseData)
        {
            var lines = responseData.split("\n");
            for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++)
            {
                if (lines[j].charAt(0) === 'F')
                    loadFile (arguments);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My first question is why I can not add "async: false" to the above options and instead I have to use `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` because otherwise it does not work.

My second question is this the correct pattern to use to do this job recursively.

My third question is how can I know when the whole process is done. I cant figure this out.

Comment: Since JavaScript cannot by its nature load files, why not handle the recursive lookup on the server side instead?

Comment: The loading of files does work (yes there is a browser stall involved) but it is an application I am developing so I am not sure what you mean with doing the loading on the server.

Comment: The reason why synchronous requests in JavaScript are a terrible idea is that JS is event driven and single threaded - if you block waiting for a request to return, the user cannot scroll or interact with anything on the page. I suggest you look into javascript loading patterns and async patterns (promises and callbacks). By the looks of it, you could benefit from using an AMD system - which could load all your files in parallel, asynchronously, and trigger your desired function once loading was complete.

Comment: That is so over my head but I will take a closer look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async: false` is the root of all evil. It is blocking your entire tab and in some cases ( like older IE ) it will block entire browser. Don't use it.

Now solution for your problem. You can do something like this:

```
// note new argument "callback"
var loadFiles = function(path, file, scope, callback) {
    var req = $.ajax({
        // some settings
        success: function(res) {
            // some processing
            for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
                loadFiles.requests.push(
                    // the same callback
                    loadFiles(path2, file2, scope2, callback)
                );
            }

            // set this request to complete
            req.completed = true;

            // check if all requests are done
            for (var i = 0; i < loadFiles.requests.length; i++) {
                if (!loadFiles.requests[i].completed) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            // TODO: you could remove completed requests from that array
            // to increase performance

            // if all are done then reset the array and run the callback
            delete loadFiles.requests;
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
    if (!loadFiles.requests || !loadFiles.requests.length) {
        loadFiles.requests = [req];
    }
    return req;
};

loadFiles(path, file, scope, function() {
    // this happens after all is done
});
```

Note that calling this function twice in a row will break it ( because `loadFiles.requests` is a property of global function ). In order to support that, you would have to wrap everything in an external function and use that function.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what does callback() do?

Comment: @gaitat This is the function that is supposed to be fired after everything is done. You define it at the end ( passed to `loadFiles` at the end of my code ). It's like AJAX's `success` callback, except it will fire after **all** jobs are complete.

Comment: I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined" at "if (!loadFiles.requests[i].completed)" and always when i is 1.

Comment: Dont I have to set completed = false somewhere?

Comment: @gaitat No, you don't have to. This error means that `requests[i]` is undefined, which means that you've probably forgot to `return req;` at the end?

Comment: Sorry but I am returning req.

Comment: @gaitat Are you pushing to the array correctly? `loadFiles.requests.push(loadFiles(path2, file2, scope2, callback));`.

Comment: I have copied your code to the letter plus the code I have to determine the parsing of files (which is mostly empty now).

Comment: @gaitat You must be doing something wrong. Post your entire code here.

Comment: The code is at http://www.virtuality.gr/AGG/EaZD-WebGL/js/EaZD/Lego.js. Of interest are lines 82 and 183.

Comment: @gaitat The code looks fine and the solution is correct. It should work. Have a look at this (simplified) jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tAh4q/ It works as it is supposed to. I guess I can't help you beyond that. Maybe you are calling this function several times in a row?